# Mongoose - data not saved to db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cant get Mongoose to save my data. I wanted to save to the database each time a new event is emitted.

```
//Capture data from socket into schema
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('slog', function (data) {
        story.lines.push ({ author: 'Khuram', text: data.my}, function (){
            story.save(function(err){
                //save line
                if (err) {throw err; }
                console.log('saved story line');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the "slog" event - Is this the one you want to cause mongoose to do the update on? Can you verify that it's actually being fired? This will help clarify if it's an issue with your call to mongoose, or the event handling code.

Comment: Yes this is the event i want mongoose to update on.  I have tested my socket.io code independently and can confirm it fires. The mongoose update with staric data as part of the push and no socket.io also works. I just think i havent merged the two functions correctly or something?

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html

Maybe you can try:

```
story.lines.push ({ author: 'Khuram', text: data.my});
story.save(function(err){
            //save line
            if (err) {throw err; }
            console.log('saved story line');
 });
```

Ultimately, it seems like the push method might not support a callback like the anonymous function you are trying to pass.

Reference: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/types/array.js

Comment: That's how i had it originally, but doing it this way, it doesnt wait to receive the socket data and continues right onto the save. I want to save data each time data is transmitted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just been playing with this a little more. Seems to be an issue more to do with Socket.io rather than mongoose, but not sure exactly what at the moment. I just tried doing a push on socket.on with some static values but it didnt work.